# How do you call your enviroment variables set in application manager using cpanel and PHP

Tags: php, cpanel, applicationmanager

### So I created a test app using Application Manager. Inside of my application path how would I call my pre set variables using PHP.

Also I would like to note I am using linux godaddy shared hosting.


additional info:

I am just trying to have somewhat "secure" environment variables and am not familiar with what the "best practice" is. In a local environment  if I was using nodejs I understand how to use dotenv.


Also, 
 
I was reading this cpanel documentation but I cant find how I call the vairables using php from my Application path.

https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/software/application-manager/82/

---

**Application Name:**

test_app

**Deployment Domain:**

mytestsite.com

**Base Application URL:**

mytestsite.com/

**Application Path:**

home/mytest-folder

**Environment Variables:**

test_var = test

Using PHP inside of home/mytest-folder how would I call or be able to get the value of my variable test_var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the environment variable using any of the following:

```
// this should work if `variables_order` includes the 'E' option
$variable = $_ENV['test_var'] ?? null;
// if not `variables_order` includes the 'E' option
// then this should work and it will also populate the '$_ENV' array with the requested variable
$variable = getenv('test_var');
// could be used as a fallback
$variable = $_SERVER['test_var'] ?? null;
```

Reference:

- [$_ENV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)
- [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)